# how to auto scroll to the newest message in recycler view?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

Hello I try may method to auto scroll down to latest message when open the chat box just like any WhatsApp or any chatting application. smoothscrolltoposition, smoothscroller and many more.[chat design image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ9ni.jpg)

please give me a solution to use this chat app just like WhatsApp when I came to this activity I want to see the latest message on the screen. and when open the keyboard to type message the last message should be above the keyboard.
[chat application image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ9ni.jpg)

the code I am using is

```
    MessageEnvironmentAdapter messageEnvironmentAdapter = new MessageEnvironmentAdapter(MessageEnvironmentActivity.this, messageModelArrayList);
    messagerecycler = findViewById(R.id.messagerecycler);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    messagerecycler.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    messagerecycler.setAdapter(messageEnvironmentAdapter);
```

to get the data from the firebase realtime database

```
    chatreference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            messageModelArrayList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                MessageModel messageModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(MessageModel.class);
                messageModelArrayList.add(messageModel);
            }
            messageEnvironmentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

to send messages data and store in realtime database

```
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            simage = snapshot.child("imageuri").getValue().toString();
            rimage = reciverimage;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
    sendmessagebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String messagetext = editmessage.getText().toString().trim();
            if (messagetext.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(MessageEnvironmentActivity.this, "please enter valid message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            editmessage.setText("");
            Date date = new Date();

            MessageModel messageModel = new MessageModel(messagetext, senderuid, date.getTime());

            database.getReference().child("chats")
                    .child(senderroom)
                    .child("messages")
                    .push()
                    .setValue(messageModel).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    database.getReference().child("chats")
                            .child(reciverroom)
                            .child("messages")
                            .push().setValue(messageModel).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I got from your question is that you want to show last message in Recyclerview above edit text. Okay that is very simple in `OnCreate` Method add
`setRecyclerView()` and since when your message arraylist is empty `messageArrayList-1` will be -1. So add `setListeners()` below `setRecyclerView()` like following

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding =FragmentGroupChatBinding.inflate(layoutInflater,container,false)
        initViews()
        setRecyclerView()
        setListeners()
        return binding.root
    }

private fun setRecyclerView() {
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity())
        adapter = MessagesAdapter(messageArrayList)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        adapter.setClickListener(this)
        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(messageArrayList.size-1)
    } 



private fun setListeners() {
    recyclerView.addOnLayoutChangeListener { v, left, top, right, bottom, oldLeft, oldTop, oldRight, oldBottom ->
        if (bottom < oldBottom) {
            if (messageArrayList.isEmpty()){
                recyclerView.postDelayed(Runnable {
                    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(messageArrayList.size) }, 100)
            }else{
                recyclerView.postDelayed(Runnable {
                    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(messageArrayList.size-1) }, 100)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

below line does the trick

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(messageArrayList.size-1)
```

**JAVA CODE**

```
private void setListeners() {
     recyclerView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, 
   int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        if (bottom < oldBottom)
            if (messageArrayList.size()==0){
             recyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(messageArrayList.size());            
                        }
                    }, 100);
         }else{
         recyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(messageArrayList.size()-1);            
                        }
                    }, 100);
       }
    }
});

}
```

Comment: hey thanks for answering, can you please give me java code for the above

Comment: @Shreyaspatne added java code. Now below  `messagerecycler.setAdapter(messageEnvironmentAdapter);` add this line recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(messageArrayList.size()); and below this call setListeners()

Comment: please elaborate where to place it exactly, the flow of code

Comment: what is that left right ,bottom in listner function

Comment: MessageEnvironmentAdapter messageEnvironmentAdapter = new MessageEnvironmentAdapter(MessageEnvironmentActivity.this, messageModelArrayList);
    messagerecycler = findViewById(R.id.messagerecycler);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    messagerecycler.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    messagerecycler.setAdapter(messageEnvironmentAdapter);
    messagerecycler.smoothScrollToPosition(messageModelArrayList.size());
    setListeners();

Comment: hi i do the same my app is working awesome. one question i dont want to run setlistner function when i already on the latest message possition can you please tell me how to do that

Comment: because when we already on last message it flash like and open up what to do to avoid that

Comment: you must call setListener(); function or your app will crash due to invalid index exception and to avoid flash comment trick line and just call setListeners() method i hope it will help